# Cannot update into database after click button

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db1 = mysql_select_db("test",$con);



     mysql_select_db("test", $con);
        $sql1="SELECT * from Vexamvenue" ;
        $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        {
    if($row1['matricNo']==$id and $row1['venue']=='')
            {
                ?>

            <form name="myform" method="GET">

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
            <tbody>

            <tr>
            <td><input name="q1" type="radio" value="paris">paris</td>
            <td><input name="q1" type="radio" value="london" >london</td>
            <td><input name="q1" type="radio" value="china" >china</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Update</button>

            </form> 

            <?php
            $b = $_GET['q1'];       
            echo $b;

            mysql_select_db("test", $con);
            $query2=("UPDATE enrl_student SET venue = '$b' WHERE matricNo = '$id';")  ;
            $query2testing = mysql_query($query2); 
            break;
        }
        elseif($row1['matricNo']==$id and $row1['venue']!='')
        {

            echo "already choose";
            break;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Hello.This is my full code for select exam venue using radio button.
The problem is, when I select the exam venue and submit, it wont update into database.

I put **$id=$_GET['id'];** because to get session. mean my url something like 
***exam.php?id=M7010***

The error is : **Notice: Undefined index: id in /srv/www/htdocs/moodle/exam.php on line 2**

If *undefined index : id* then how it can pass the 1st condition.

What I want : 
**table before update**
|matricNo|venue|
|M7010   |NULL |

**table after update**
|matricNo|venue|
|M7010   |paris|

*if selected Paris

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a get form, it changes your get parameters. You have to add your id as hidden field in your form.
It also would be better to use post forms for changing data.

You also should read about SQL injections ;-)